# Why does my system use 2 GB of memory when I have only one application(chrome) running?

Tags: updates, ram

[image]Here are two pictures of the processes and Resources tabs of my System Monitor.
Also, do you think updating the system to 16 could solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Chrome's design is such that it uses a *lot* of memory, in exchange for speed and security of the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, open the terminal and show the output of the command
    `free -m`

Probably, 2gb is already used because some memory was used for file cache purpose. It completely ok and speeds up overall system speed.

Please, read more on this website: [www.linuxatemyram.com](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

PS. And looks like your Chrome is ok, there is no need to replace it.